# Getting HTML object collection when trying to get linkbutton by name

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = foo;

    function foo() {
        var e = document.getElementsByName("<%=foo.ClientID %>");
        alert(e);
    }
</script>
```

I get "HTML object collection" I am calling this method in default.aspx. I have the linkbutton in a user control.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `getElementsByTagName` which returns a collection that have that tag name.  Tag name is `input` or `h1` and not the **name** attribute.

You want `getElementById` instead.

If you need to get more than one thing (remember, `id` is unique) then give each link button a class and use `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: I can't get element by ID because the linkbutton is inside a repeator control. So the id's are different for the itemtemplates.

Comment: Then give each one a class and use `getElementsByClassName`